# How to float product div to the left instead of the right

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I can't seem to align the product grid so that items appear from the left, instead of the right:

http://penarthpc.com/~dronebo2/wp/shop/tshirts/

Everything I do just messes up the template file, am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:right` to `#shop-menu-left`

```
#container #content #shop-content #shop-menu-left {
float: right;
width: 240px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#container #content #shop-content #shop-right #product{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#container{
  float:right;
  margin-left:...px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML

```
<div id="shop-content">

  <div id="shop-menus">
  </div>

  <div id="shop-items">
  </div>

</div>
```

and in your CSS:

```
#shop-content {
  float:both;
}

#shop-menus {
  float:right;
}

# shop-items{
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
float: ((left or right or where you want));
```

in the CSS file